# I'm unable to compile Phoenix on OSX (10.6.7)

Tags: python, macos

Using python that's installed by default on OSX, I'm trying to run phoenix 
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Phoenix_miner
and I'm getting:

```
python phoenix.py 
  import itertools, md5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "phoenix.py", line 29, in <module>
    import minerutil
  File "/Users/george/Downloads/phoenix-1.4/minerutil/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from RPCProtocol import RPCClient
  File "/Users/george/Downloads/phoenix-1.4/minerutil/RPCProtocol.py", line 30, in <module>
    from twisted.web.iweb import IBodyProducer
ImportError: cannot import name IBodyProducer
```

Can anyone advise how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to upgrade your version of Twisted.   11.0 should work; it did for me.  Try

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade twisted
```

[This assumes that easy_install is going to pick up the system python.  If it's in a weird state, try `sudo python_version path_to_easy_install --upgrade twisted`.]

Comment: This fails.  https://gist.github.com/1047422

I suspect due to python being installed compiled universal, and ppc toolchain not being installed.  What to do?

Answer (score 0):

I installed MacPorts, installed python27 to /opt/local/bin/python, downloaded the Twisted-11.0.0 source, and compiled it using python27. I compiled and installed pyopencl from source as well, and now I can run phoenix.py, on Mac 10.6.6.